# How to solve error DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I got this error suddenly when I was surfing.

I deleted temp files and I cleaned cache, but it still did not work.

I solved with:

1. Open Windows services Manager (Windows key + r and put services.msc)
2. Restart DNS Client

Answer (score 0):

please enter this URL **chrome://settings/security** in the chrome web browser  . after navigating to the chrome security settings, under the "**Use Secure DNS**" option, please select "**with your current service provider**" option. now it will work as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Possibly this step by step guide could help you https://www.mobileyouth.org/fixing-dns_probe_finished_bad_config-chrome/
Turn off your cable modem -
Turn off the router -
Turn off your PC -
Turn on the router and factory reset it -
Turn on your PC and connect to the router, you should be able to use the   192.168.0.1 as you will have received an IP address from the router when you turned your machine back on.-
Change the Administrator password on the router.  There are many routers that can be compromised from the Internet if you do not change this password. -
Set up your wireless, change the default password.-
Turn off your PC -
Turn off the router -
Turn on the cable modem -
Turn on the router -
Turn on your PC